# Excel VBA - get cell value as RTF formatted text

Tags: excel, vba, rtf

I want to get the formatted text of an excel cell as RTF using VBA (to store the formatted text in a database).
If it's not possible to get the text as RTF, how could I store the formatted text in a database and keep the formatting?

Thanks!

Comment: reverse engineer the formatting by formatting another cell to match. write a macro that can format and reformat the text - something like a template macro. I dont think it's possible to export the formatting of a cell as rtf. in simple words - you need to store the text as text with no formatting and then a metadata macro to store the formatting

Comment: or save the workbook as a webpage and then edit the page with notepad. you will see the meta (xml) formatting of your cells there but then still you need a macro to read that data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you also have Word then you can use Automation. The following code copy the cell into a new Word application and save it as rtf file.

```
Sub SaveRTF()
   Dim objWD As Word.Application
   Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

   Set objWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   objWD.Documents.Add
   Set wdDoc = objWD.ActiveDocument
   wdDoc.Select
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Copy 'Change cell reference and sheet name
   objWD.Selection.Paste
   wdDoc.SaveAs2 "C:\\Users\\YourName\\Documents\\FormatFile.rtf", wdFormatRTF 'Change File Name here
   wdDoc.Close

   Set wdDoc = Nothing
   Set objWD = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You also need to add Reference to MS Word Object Library